# Calling Java method in Android from JavaScript using webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

I'm trying to access my Java method `helloWorld`(); using `JavaScriptInterface` in Android, from the page I'm viewing using `WebView`

I'm a little new to this, and I don't know why I'm not getting the value to my html page

This is the Android code I'm using:

```
WebView web;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://exampleweb:10110/exWeb/deposits.jsp");
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    private Activity activity;

    public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String helloWorld(){
        return("hello world");
    }
}
```

}

This is the JavaScript code I've been using (on the page I'm viewing with WebView)

**HTML button**

```
<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary connectToAndroid">Test android</button></td>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".connectToAndroid").on('click', function () {
var val = window.JSInterface.helloWorld();
alert(val);
});
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I just want to alert an "Hello World" from android in my HTML page.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try putting a log in `helloWorld` and see if its being called.

Comment: why do you call it by WINDOW.JSinterface and not directly by JSInterface ?

Comment: @r4phG I don't know why actually, I've been trying to follow some guides on the internet. I'll try without "window".

Comment: @Rohit5k2 It doesn't seem like it's getting called actually.

Comment: @Coderap Have You tried ? :D

Comment: @r4phG Yes I tried without "WINDOW" but nothing happens, I think I've missed something here.

Comment: did you load jquery before using it? try to use javascript instead of jquery and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very weird, I tried using this a couple of hours ago:

```
$(".connectToAndroid").on('click', function () {
  var val = Android.helloWorld();
  alert(val);
 });
```

Then I changed it, it didn't say Android anymore,

yet I kept getting an error saying:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Android is not defined
```

And after a while I figured, `Android.helloWorld();` must be cached somehow in my webview app or something.

So, I changed back to this:

```
$(".connectToAndroid").on('click', function () {
  var val = Android.helloWorld();
  alert(val);
 });
```

And added this:

```
web.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "Android");
```

And now it works like a charm, as it should have from the beginning if it wasn't for some cache somewhere,

Can anyone explain why this happens? Does android webview actually cache javascript code? And can I prevent this behaviour in the future somehow? Cache bothers a lot when coding/testing new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding this line of code before loading the url and make sure you reference your jQuery library in the html.

```
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(this));
```

Comment: I will give you an upvote, not because you solved the answer, but this did help me with displaying the " alert ". When I managed to pass the data, the alert didn't work yet, but by adding this line of code, I could alert the data aswell. Thank you :)

Comment: @Coderap Glad that I helped :)